# Papervision Carousel

Tags: actionscript-3, papervision3d, carousel

Hey guys I was wondering how to create a carousel like 
[this](https://www.hsbc.gr/1/2/el/world-selection?WT.ac=HBGR_WorldSelectionInvestmentProductsPage)

with papervision. I created one but the planes just go round and round. I was wondering if it's possible for the planes to keep the same angel as the example of the link. I do not want the plane to rotate itself on the y axis but just move on the X/Z axis just going around an object in the middle.

I am using FlashBuilder for this.

Comment: Regarding Papervision, check out the lookAt method (http://papervision3d.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/as3/trunk/docs/org/papervision3d/objects/DisplayObject3D.html#lookAt()) Back to the carousel: that looks like a 2D carousel (just scale is used)...have a look at the bottom of this page for some free video tutorials: http://gotoandlearn.com/index.php?currentpage=9 . Here's an example of a Flash Player 10 3D carousel(no PV3D required) http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=92

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the planes to rotate you don't need Papervision at all and my advice is to avoid it unless it's necessary.

In your example the x position and size can be easily calculated using sine and cosine function. There is also some blur filter applied when the plane is far from us and you will also have to take care of the z-sorting - that is the close objects are rendered on top of those far from us.

Altogether is't easier than dealing with Papervision and you can customize it much better. And you will learn useful techniques :).

Comment: I did something like that by using the sine and cosine functions to calculate the x and z positions. I had to play with the display list children positions in order to switch positions of the object in the middle with the one that was supposed to to pass behind it and again switched them back. Don't know why but the papervision made it so much easier. I have to admit though that the planes do not render the moving pictures clearly with papervision. Don't know maybe I will avoid papervision after all and use my code. Thanks for the direction though.

Comment: I have experience with both approaches and I have found these reasons for not to use PV3D unless it's necessary: 1. PV3D is big library and will bloat your output (SWF), 2. PV3D is resource intensive, 3. PV3D is complicated and not fully documented, 4. PV3D has it's own bugs and issues.

Comment: What pisses me off is that the papervision version works great but the CPU usage is high and always hangs for a second or two after a few spins. Anyway thanks